# UIViewController with tableView or TableViewController in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll, uiviewcontroller, swift3

I would like to have an advice concerning the use of UIViewController and TableViewController.

I would like to do something which is like that:

[image]

When I scroll down, the textView is adjusted.

Is it possible to do that with a tableViewController or do I need to use a "normal" UIViewController and place a TableView inside ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, as for me, to do that - it's adding UITextView inside header of UITableView. No matter if it's UIViewController or UITableViewController.

It's very similar to Parallax effect. You can find examples of parallax UITableView in a gitHub, for example you can look on this Parallax demo: https://github.com/runmad/ParallaxAutoLayoutDemo